# SwiftUI About ZStack & NaviagtonLink

Tags: swiftui

I use ZStack & NaviagtonLink in SwiftUI.

```
ZStack{
  List{
    NavigationLink(destination: NextView()) {
       Text("Hi")
    }
  } 
  Text("Hello")
}
```

This view is valid as I expected, and there are the text "Hello" on List's columns.

But even in NavigationLink ZStack is valid and in NextView there is hello.

I want to display it only this view, and I don't want to display it in NextView,

Please tell me how to fix.

Thank you.

Comment: Make it conditional`if` the `NavigationLink` `isActive` don't show `else` show

Answer (score 2):

Embed in navigationView otherwise navigation link cannot work

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{
        ZStack{
            List{
                NavigationLink(destination: NextView()) {
                    Text("Hi")
                }
            }
            Text("Hello")
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
    
}

}
```

Comment: Oh, it isn't good due we cannot hide TabBar like we do in UIKit with `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`